# JS Why does my async function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm beginning to understand async / await but I haven't figured it out yet. I really hope you can help me!

```
async function test1() {
  const fetchPromise = await fetch("https://www.instagram.com/boarirkeerd/?__a=1", {})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response["graphql"]['user']['id']); /* returns 43000480694 */
    return response["graphql"]['user']['id']; /* returns undefined */
  });};

if (await test1 == "43000480694") {console.log("YES");}
else {console.log('NO');} /* returns NO */
test1(); /* undefined */
```

The JS console shows:
NO
Promise
43000480694

Why is it in that order and why does the function return undefined?
It should be:
YES
Promise
43000480694

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Because you return nothing from `test1`. You `return` from the promise callback, and the awaited value is then in `fetchPromise`. But you're not returning *that* from `test1`.

Comment: try changing `await test1` to `await test1()`

Comment: You also shouldn't mix `await` and `then`: `const resp = await fetch(..); const val = await resp.json(); return val[..];`.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a function to return something, it must at least have the `return` keyword.
2. To reference a function, use `test1`, to call a function, use `test1()`. The `()` are required.